# Replace 3 first elements of string by other 2 from keyboard in C

Tags: c

I don't know how to Replace 3 first elements of string by other 2 from keyboard in C.
Can I change the 2th and 3th and print from the 2th?

Comment: Think of strings as *arrays of characters* (because that's what they really are). If you know how to use arrays of integers and know how to access single elements of such arrays, then you can handle arrays of characters and how to access single elements of those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[] = "my string";
    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<strlen(c); i++){
        if(i==0 || i==1 || i==2){
            printf("Enter a character to replace %dth element: ", i+1);
            scanf(" %c", &c[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nString is: %s", c);
}
```

In the following code, we have treated string as an array and in the `for loop` there is a `if` statement which checks for the first 3 characters of the string
then we just replace the letters using scanf, in `scanf(" %c", &c[i]);`, NOTE that there is a space before `%c`, it is because if that is not done the 2nd scanf will get skipped because of the new line from 1st `scanf()`.

Answer (score -1):

that would not be doing what you are asked to do (modify the strings first 3 chars).

Not going to provide actual code, have a go from these hints. If you get stuck post actual code

- create new string thats one shorter that length of old string +1
- put new 2 chars in new string at pos 0 and 1
- copy 4th char onwards (offset 3) into new string at 3rd position (offset 2)